# How do I make python program run faster using pypy?

Tags: python, pypy

I have installed PyPy and rpython in my system.I have barely started with PyPy so forgive me for my inability to grasp any new terms in advance:

> 1.PyPy post sym link upon usage for execution of program ex: pypy myprogram.py does it yeild faster result or does it mimic an interpreter?
>
> 2.Whats the significance of usage of rpython and employing JIT based translation? How to use it?
>
> 3.Does bare PyPy usage reduces my code's runtime or I should go for transaltion and then run the code to get significant change in run time (I did see a video where image processing is done in realtime or almost realtime using pypy and when compared to python its was like hell of fast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5ad6NpjR3M&t=539s )?
>
> 4.I did run the command pypy myprogram.py and got similar execution time as using python myprogram.py? Where am I going wrong? I have used multiprocessing and threading to optimizing the code but I think thats pretty much the limit of me in terms of optimizing! So what are my options in dragging down the execution time with or without usage(maybe some other JIT compiler) of pypy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. You can answer all these questions for yourself with a bit of elbow grease and a couple of simple benchmarks.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. I apologise. Can you just guide me with some resource to start with?

Comment: Start with Google.

Comment: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-fast-is-pypy .  (And no, you should not use RPython.)